# how to get file path from uri path in android

Tags: android, image-processing

Given URI:

content://com.app.exam.provider/files/image/a590d119-f234-482e-9218-1d89f9829a8b.jpg

I am loading via glide, working. but i also need acces to file to upload image.

Answer (score 0):

For taking the file path from the available uri; use this:-

`String file_path = yourUri.uri.getpath();`

Also to get file object from this uri:-

`File file_obj = new File(new URI(file_path));`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code to get the filename from an image URI.

```
/**
 *
 * @param image
 * @return
 */
private String getImageFilename(Uri image) {
    if (image != null) {
        String path = getRealPathFromURI(this.context(), image);
        if (path != null) {
            return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Gets the file path from a given URI.
 * @param context
 * @param contentUri
 * @return
 */
private String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        if (contentUri != null) {
            String[] tempArray = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, tempArray, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        printLogMessage(e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this doesn't work in your case.